# Problems with dbm module under python 3 using Beaker

Tags: python, beaker, dbm

Im having trouble using Beaker on windows 7. Im using python 3, and i understand there are problems with the dbm module for python 3 under windows. The error im getting when i attempt to start my module is:

`ImportError: No module named _dbm`

Poking about with the python console, the error arises when i attempt to import `ndbm` from the dbm module, Any suggestions as to how i can get around this?

Im using python 3.2.2 (AMD 64) and windows 7

Answer (score 0):

[The docs for dbm.ndbm](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/dbm#module-dbm.ndbm%5d) say that it's only available on Unix. On Windows, your options are `dbm.dumb` or the third-party [pybsddb](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm).

Comment: That would lead the conclusion that beaker is going to be a non starter on windows....

Comment: The docs for Beaker say that it can use "File-based, DBM files, memcached, memory, and database back-ends." I'm sure some of those will work on Windows.